# Issue with Lightning:input and currency formatter (Aura Component and LWC)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightninginput

I'm creating a lightning component with a `lightning:input`, but I have an issue with decimal places and `currency formatter`.

This is my code:

```
<lightning:input name="foo" value="foo" type="number" formatter="currency" step="0.01"/>
```

Without decimal places is saved correctly:

```
Input: 3
Saved value: 3.00
```

But with decimal places it saves a wrong value:

```
Input: 0.03
Saved value: 3.00
```

Another example:

```
Input: 4.32
Saved value: 432.00
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

SOLVED! I wasn't serializing the list to JSON. Sending as JSON to the apex controller and deserializing in the apex controller solved the issue :).

**UPDATE 2**

I faced this issue again with a LWC datatable, and the solution is the same. Here is the code for anyone who needs it:

LWC

```
saveAccounts({listAccounts:JSON.stringify(this.draftValues)})
.then(...
```

Apex Controller

```
public static void saveAccounts(String listAccounts){
    try{
        update (List<Account>)JSON.deserialize(listAccounts, List<Account>.class);
        ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a logic in between as how are you collecting the value from the input component and then saving it? With what you have as input, your saved value should match. Also, what is the field type where you are saving the values?

Comment: Any logic, just saving the field as recived. The field type is currency (16,2). Having the same problem with other fields with percentages (8,2).

Comment: I verified with a quick test and it works as expected. The values as passed from the component is saved exactly the way it should be. You should verify if there's any other logic viz., trigger, workflow rule, etc. on that field which is causing this issue. There's no problem in the component itself.

Comment: Testing I've seen that the helper sends `3.2` and the apex controller is receiving `32` (Sending and receiving a `List<CustomObject__c`). Is in that point were the value changes :S.

Comment: SOLVED! I wasn't serializing the list to JSON. Sending as JSON to the apex controller and deserializing in the apex controller solved the issue :).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :`<lightning:input name="foo" value="foo" type="currency" step="0.01"/>`